# Return inserted item's UUID back from Dapper/PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, dapper

I have a model object like so in my ASP.Net Core 2.1 Web API Project:

```
public class Tenant
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And am executing an insert into postgres like this:

```
public async Task<int> CreateItem(Tenant item)
{
    return await db.ExecuteAsync($@"INSERT INTO tenants (Name) VALUES (@Name)", item);
}
```

I need the Guid back, to drive the subsequent logic.  It returns the affectedrows (1).  My research shows a few tricks being used for getting back the autoincrement ID (like using 'MAX' and so forth).

Is there a way to do this, via dapper preferably?  Or do I need to drop back to ADO.Net?

Comment: How are you populating the Guid value for the record ?

Comment: What's stopping you from generating the Id in code using `Guid.NewGuid();`?

Comment: For reference, was allowing the DB to generate them.  Whether true or not, I've read in more than one place that generating them outside the DB can lead to rare but annoying conflicts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to use the RETURNING clause of the INSERT statement to have Postgres return the inserted id.

```
public async Task<Guid> CreateItem(Tenant item)
{
    return await db.ExecuteScalarAsync<Guid>($@"INSERT INTO tenants (Name) VALUES (@Name) RETURNING Id", item);
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly!  Thanks for your help, I hadn't come across the ExecuteScalarAsync<T> method.